# Need help in replacing a "[some word][space][more words]" to [some word] in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, replace, substring

I have a the below data.

```
    Company
1   Progressive Corp.
2   Travelers Companies Inc.
3   Progressive Finance  Corp.
4   Zurich Insurance Group (3)
5   Zurich Financial Services Ltd
6   Zurich  Ltd
7   Berkshire Hathaway Inc.
8   Auto-Owners Insurance Co.
9   Berkshire Finance Inc.
10  AmTrust Financial Services
```

For example: I need to replace all the string contains "Zurich"(4,5,6) with "Zurich [some word]"

Comment: I notice that your example data does  not seem to contain any strings that we are supposed to replace.

Comment: Your sample data and expected output are not very specific; generally, there are different ways of approaching your problem, but it's difficult to say how well any of these approaches generalise to your larger dataset as you don't provide enough information. For example, do you always replace `"[some word][space][more words]"` with `"[some word] US"`? The key here is to provide *minimal yet representative* sample data and provide matching expected output.

Comment: For the example you have given `gsub` would work. `gsub(pattern, replacement, string)`. However, if you have multiple different changes you want to make then you'll have to try something else.

Comment: I have the above data and i need to  replace "[some word][space][more words]" to  "[some word]".

Comment: So `"Zurich Insurance Group (3)”` should become `”Zurich”` and `"Berkshire Finance Inc.”` should become `“Berkshire”`?

Comment: Yes, If we find a row with "Zurich" inside it, replace that row with "Zurich"

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague since we are not told the structure in which the data is stored in. However **assuming that the data is stored in a data frame**, the following code should work:

```
company.data = data.frame(
c("Progressive Corp.",
"Travelers Companies Inc.",
"Progressive Finance  Corp.",
"Zurich Insurance Group (3)",
"Zurich Financial Services Ltd",
"Zurich  Ltd",
"Berkshire Hathaway Inc.",
"Auto-Owners Insurance Co.",
"Berkshire Finance Inc.",
"AmTrust Financial Services"), stringsAsFactors = F)

names(company.data) = "company"

change.index = which(grepl("Zurich", company.data$company))

company.data$company[change.index] = "Zurich"

> company.data
                      company
1           Progressive Corp.
2    Travelers Companies Inc.
3  Progressive Finance  Corp.
4                      Zurich
5                      Zurich
6                      Zurich
7     Berkshire Hathaway Inc.
8   Auto-Owners Insurance Co.
9      Berkshire Finance Inc.
10 AmTrust Financial Services
```